# Probability Distribution (solve for k)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I don't know how to get this question started so a push in the right direction would be a great help. Here is the question;

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability distribution:
>   $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
> x & 1 & 2 &3 & 4\\\hline
> P(X=x) & 1k & 2k & 3k & 4k
> \end{array}$$

**(a) Solve for k**

... so how would I use the formula to input this information in to find $k$?

You guys do not have to solve for all the $k$'s. Just show me how to solve for one of the $k$'s, and then I think I can do the rest. Thank you!

Comment: All the $k$s are probably supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that for discrete random variables, 
$$\sum_{x}P(X = x) = 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is that $$\sum_{i=1}^4P(X=i)=1.$$ Given $P(X=i)=ik$, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^4P(X=i)=\sum_{i=1}^4ik=10k=1,$$ and thus $k=\frac{1}{10}$.